# Use cell reference to define array in VB

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I'm trying to use a cell reference to define an array rather than needing to change the macro each time the required worksheets change.

I have the required sheets listed in cell B29 of the sheet, so I attempted

```
.Sheets(Array(WorkSheets("Approver 4").Range("B29"))).Copy
```

but this did not work.

So at the moment I'm stuck listing the sheet names as such:

```
.Sheets(Array("Scenario Summary", "Scenario 1-3 ML(JA) Logon Pages", "Scenario 4-6 ML(ZH) Logon Pages", "Scenario 7-9 ML(ZH) Logon Pages", "Approver 4")).Copy

Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

'Copy the sheets to a new workbook
With Sourcewb
    Set TheActiveWindow = ActiveWindow
    Set TempWindow = .NewWindow
    'copy the below sheet names from the Worksheets cell (B29) on the worksheet
    .Sheets(Array("Scenario Summary", "Scenario 1-3 ML(JA) Logon Pages", "Scenario 4-6 ML(ZH) Logon Pages", "Scenario 7-9 ML(ZH) Logon Pages", "Approver 4")).Copy
End With
```

Any suggestions?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your cell `B29` contains a comma seperated list without quotes and no extra spaces, try

```
.Sheets(Split(WorkSheets("Approver 4").Range("B29"),",")).Copy
```

Expected data in `B29`

```
Scenario Summary,Scenario 1-3 ML(JA) Logon Pages,Scenario 4-6 ML(ZH) Logon Pages,Scenario 7-9 ML(ZH) Logon Pages,Approver 4
```

Note won't work if any of your sheet names include a `,`